# java.io.FileNotFoundException when I'm trying to read into a binary file in my Android Studio project

Tags: java, android, android-studio, filenotfoundexception, file-not-found

As the titles says, i want to read into a binary file, "**mac_address_name**", that is already created.
The project is runned on a physical device connected to the android studio IDE.

Here's my project tree, you can see the classes and the binary file :

[PROJECT TREE.PNG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RfJ1D.png)

Here's the code in the **ProcessorManager** class, you can see in comments every other ways i tried to do it...

```
private String readFromFile() {

    String ret = "";

    try {

        /*InputStream inputStream = main_activity.getApplicationContext().openFileInput("mac_address_name");*/
        /*InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File("../mac_address_name"));*/
        /*InputStream inputStream = main_activity.openFileInput("mac_address_name");*/
        InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File("mac_address_name"));
        if ( inputStream != null ) {
            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
            String receiveString = "";
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            while ( (receiveString = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null ) {
                stringBuilder.append("\n").append(receiveString);
            }

            inputStream.close();
            ret = stringBuilder.toString();
        }
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("login activity", "File not found: " + e.toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("login activity", "Can not read file: " + e.toString());
    }

    return ret;
}
```

And the output :

> E/login activity: File not found: java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   mac_address_name: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Comment: i created and assets folder and used Ivan Shafran's answer and it worked thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this purpose, you should use assets.
Move the file to the src/main/assets folder inside your project.
Then use AssetsManager to get file content:

```
AssetManager am = context.getAssets();
InputStream is = am.open("mac_address_name");
```

More info at: 
https://nbasercode.com/net/android-read-text-file-from-assets-folder-in-android-studio/
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager

Comment: I don't have an asset folder but i got src/main/res, can i add it manually to my project and it will recognize it ?

Comment: @ArminKiani, Yeah, create that folder manually. This is the standard directory for that. The android build will recognize it